# How can I mine ALT SHA-256 coins using a Bitmain S4?

Tags: cgminer, altcoin, hash, hashpower

The bitmain S4 does 2TH/s out of the box with no overclocking.  For many alt SHA-256 coins, this can be 10% - 50% of the entire network hashing power, which would allow us to gain alt coins quickly, especially when the difficulty is low.  However, the S4 does not work with most mining pools except for BtcGuild and Slush's pool.  In fact, I have yet to find any Alt sha-256 pools that it works with consistently.

The problem seems to be in the fact that the version of cgminer the S4 uses does not support vardiff and can only mine at a diff setting of 2048.

Does anyone know of working alt sha-256 pools which have fixed diff ports at 2048?
I'm especially interested in switching pools which can mine several alt coins at max hash rate for the S4 specifically.

Please make sure the pool is working stably with an S4 before posting.

Comment: `does not support vardiff and can only mine at a diff setting of 2048` That seems curiously specific. Do you mind if I ask how you determined that?

Comment: There is a discussion about that limitation here : https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=796839.740  Apparently the manufacturer knows about it too.  Even ckolivas (the author of cgminer) gets into the conversation. He also released an improved version of cgminer for the S4 which is what I'm using, but it still cannot attach to any alt coin pools I've found.